# the data of products dont appear in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with  product's table of my database.

When user insert product it is displayed in site with no error, 
but the product not displayed in mysql database.

```
mysql_query("
     INSERT INTO `products` (`p_name`, `owner_id` ,`cat`, `type`, `price`, `details`, `photo`)
     VALUES ('$_POST[p_name]', '$_SESSION[owner_id]', '$_POST[cat]', '$_POST[type]', '$_POST[price]', '$_POST[details]', '$img.$fileExt')
    ");
```

Comment: Theres not enough information to answer the question. Where are you displaying? You are open to SQL injections. You shouldn't use `mysql_` functions.

Comment: i dont understand. product data is found in the web site but not found in the database

Comment: How is on the website but not in the DB? You have written static pages?

Comment: @arnas, are you using the command line to query it? Is that why you are saying it's not in the mysql database? If so, my guess is that your access privileges are too low. You need root access on your development environment.

Comment: i try to explain .the product is found in site image of product name of product and the price .all this data are found on the website but when i enter to the database in products table . its empty why ? and if there is an error how does the website display a product with no data?

Comment: i deleted the table and created  new table.its worked but i dont know how this was occured ? anyway thank you for replying

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: the question IMHO should be deleted since it is unclear and was caused by something unknown.

Comment: You should stop using a deprecated and insecure API

Answer (score -2):

VALUES ('".$_POST[p_name]."') i assume if the value in the single quote, it will be a string and the value of the post wont passing there. try to put single quote double dot with double quote inside the post value

Comment: This comment is a little hard to follow, plus this also completely skips the really important step of **properly escaping the string**.